# Generate a new list on iterating a list with the iterating item, previous item and next item

Tags: python, algorithm, list

There is a list of 15 elements. From this list I would like with each iteration the x. item, and item x - 1 and x + 1 and generate a new list.

Example: in the 4. iteration I am at 4th item, and I want to get the 3rd and 5th item and generate a new list. newlist = [3,4,5] In the next iteration at 5. item, I want to get the item 4th and 6th and generate a new list and so on.

If the item the iteration is on the first item, it should take only the next and his self. If the item is the last on the list, it should take only the previous item and his self.

Short: if the iteration at x, take x-1, x and x+1 to a new list. before the next iteration clear the list like list.clear()

The algorithm schema as a excel table:
[image]

My code try, (but I think it can be better):

```
list_ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_list = []
for item in list_:
    print("POS:", list_.index(item))
    if list_.index(item) == 0:
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)])
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item+1)])
        print(new_list)
        new_list.clear()
        print("*"*55)
    elif list_.index(item) >= 1 and list_.index(item) < len(list_)-1:
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)-1])
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)])
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)+1])
        print(new_list)
        new_list.clear()
        print("*"*55)
    elif list_.index(item) <= len(list_):
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)-1])
        new_list.append(list_[list_.index(item)])
        print(new_list)
        new_list.clear()
        print("*"*55)
```

Output:

```
POS: 0
[0, 1]
*******************************************************
POS: 1
[0, 1, 2]
*******************************************************
POS: 2
[1, 2, 3]
*******************************************************
POS: 3
[2, 3, 4]
*******************************************************
POS: 4
[3, 4, 5]
*******************************************************
POS: 5
[4, 5, 6]
*******************************************************
POS: 6
[5, 6, 7]
*******************************************************
POS: 7
[6, 7, 8]
*******************************************************
POS: 8
[7, 8, 9]
*******************************************************
POS: 9
[8, 9, 10]
*******************************************************
POS: 10
[9, 10]
*******************************************************
```

Some better ways or more efficient algorithms are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list slices to achieve that:

```
list_ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_list = [list_[max(0, i-1):i+2] for i in range(len(list_))]
```

Giving you:

```
[[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
[9, 10]]
```

Or if you really want to just iterate over it without storing to a new list (i.e. an equivalent of your code):

```
list_ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(len(list_)):
    new_list = list_[max(0, i-1):i+2]
    print(new_list)
    # no need to clear it as it will be overwritten on the next loop anyway
    print("*" * 55)
```